# Incorrect preview of fenced code block within an ordered list

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-preview

The preview for a fenced code block within an ordered list:

[image: Markdown fenced code block within an ordered list]

This is the actual result after posting:

[image: Inline code]

The fenced code block turned into inline code! The preview is wrong.

1.
`scheme (doc id: 1 title: "First document" "First sentence" "Second sentence.")`

2.
`scheme (let (((my-name "XYZ")) (doc title: "Second document"`

Answer (score -1):

The reason this is possible is because the code isn't properly numbered on the list and Markdown got confused, leading to thinking it is a single line of code.

And doing:

````
```something```
````

This happens:

`something`

The way how it goes is: `there's code -> let's close it -> there's code -> something -> let's close it -> there's code -> let's close it`

So in order to fix it, do it this way (Just don't select and copy this. I used an invisible character to layer it properly.):

````
1. ```scheme
   (doc id: 1
       title: "First document"
       "First sentence."
       "Second sentence.")
   ‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​‎​```
````

And it should now be:

1. ```
   (doc id: 1
       title: "First document"
       "First sentence."
       "Second sentence.")
   ```

> Problem solved.

Comment: Um, yes. But the OP did not ask how we can improve, but why it is different

Comment: @ppwater Recheck. Is that better?

Comment: I think this still comes down to being a bug since the preview renderer is not working the same way as the backend renderer. This can only be fixed by devs